# how to use redis pipeline for nested method

Tags: python, redis

I want to use redis pipeline for below method:

```
def func(self):
    .....
    result = redis.smembers(key)
    for i in result:
        self.other_func(i)

    if redis.scard(key) == 0:
            redis.delete(key)

def other_func(self, value):
    .....
    redis.set(key, value)
```

I write like this, is it right?

```
def func(self):
    .....
    with redis.pipeline() as pipe:
        result = pipe.smembers(key)
        for i in result:
            self.other_func(i)

        if pip.scard(key) == 0:
                pip.delete(key)

def other_func(self, value):
    .....
    redis.set(key, value)
```

How about `other_func`? Do I need to pass the `pipe` to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need to use `pipe` for all the commands that you want to send in the same pipeline